# Gmail not accepting mail

Tags: postfix, gmail

I'm setting up a new mail server with postfix dovecot and things are working fine except this strange thing. I'm unable to send email to gmail addresses. The log shows status sent. However, I checked there is no email in gmail mailbox.

```
Jul  8 13:10:08 example postfix/smtp[5294]: B53B637C233: to=<some-address@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in-v4v6.l.google.com[173.194.79.26]:25, delay=2.2, delays=1.5/0.08/0.49/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1341727808 nc7si50672387pbc.75)
```

However, my other account can send to gmail. After several testing, then I found that if I first send email from gmail, then subsequently I can send from my server and email received by gmail.

I don't have this issue with Yahoo. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do your SPF records look like?

Comment: If I check the mail server domain mail.example.com, it says "v=spf1 a -all". But on example.com, it does not return any record. This is from http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Comment: The e-mail has been accepted by gmail.  Go talk to them about why they failed to deliver it to the mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The logs say "sent". So the mail has been sent by you and **accepted** by Google.

Google then (probably) found your mail "spammy" and discarded it. This is a Google mail processing problem which can only be solved by Google itself. Or send mails that don't look spammy. Follow these instructions for example: [E-mail sent with postfix are marked as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/128990/e-mail-sent-with-postfix-are-marked-as-spam?rq=1)